# I was wondering how do I use ASCII color codes with in a an ENUM

Tags: java

The project Im working on i need to use single private instance variable for each enumeration
constant of type string that stores an ASCII colour value as well as a constructor to go with it.

```
public enum Category {
    private static final String Red = "\033[0;31m";
    private static final String white = "\033[0;37m";
    private static final String blue = "\033[0;34m";
    private static final String purple = "\033[0;35m";
    private static final String yellow = "\033[0;33m";
     private static final String green = "\033[0;32m";
Category(String Red, String white, String Blue, String purple, String yellow, String green) 
{


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as below

```
public enum Category {
    RED  ("\033[0;31m"),
    WHITE  ("\033[0;37m"),
    BLUE  ("\033[0;34m"),
    PURPLE  ("\033[0;35m"),
    YELLOW  ("\033[0;33m"),
    GREEN  ("\033[0;32m"); 
    private final String color;
    private Category(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```